# Where to get AES GCM NIST-like test cases

Tags: aes, implementation, gcm, nist, test-vectors

I'm implementing AES GCM 256 bit at the moment.  Now I'm finished with copying the content of the standard as a program and now have to make it actually work.  With the test cases in the official NIST specification (https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf) and the original one (https://luca-giuzzi.unibs.it/corsi/Support/papers-cryptography/gcm-spec.pdf) I immediately found out – not surprisingly – that my implementation was wrong.  Now I'm trying to debug it like I did successfully for AES (without GCM) and SHA previously, but now my problem is that I couldn't find any suitable test cases.  The original specification has some, but since I implemented it with the NIST one I don't understand what the symbols mean and others I found online had not enough  intermediate steps for me to figure out where the problem(s) lie(s).  Where can I find working test cases with many intermediate steps using the convention of the NIST specification (or alternatively is there anywhere a translation between the two notations)?

Comment: AFAIK NIST only provides test vectors. http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/mac/gcmtestvectors.zip You can use existing libraries to test your code.

Comment: I don't need to test my code – I know it's wrong.  I need test cases with enough information about the values in intermediate steps that I can figure out where the errors lie.  And I don't need test cases published by NIST, the thing I need is test cases where the steps are labeled in a way I – someone who implemented it with NIST – can understand.

Comment: You can modify some other codes to label as you wanted so that you can test each part of your code.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try this.

Comment: While generally a good idea, sadly I can't get any implementation working for me.

Comment: You can find the GCM test vectors here: https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/cryptographic-algorithm-validation-program/cavp-testing-block-cipher-modes#GCMVS